# New Issue for previously working code to find all AD groups a user is a member of (Some or all identity references could not be translated)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, active-directory

I have code that returns a list of all AD Groups the current user of a Windows Forms application is a member of.  This is used to determine access rights.  It has worked fine for a while, but all of the sudden it does not work and returns the error "Some or all identity references could not be translated".  Note this error does not occur when I am in the Virtual Machine debugging the code, but only when I publish it and try to access it from our company's shared drive.  It may be due to some network security change and be related to domain permissions or something similar, but my IT Department is not helpful in this regard.

The error is on the line below:

```
Dim group As String = id_ref.Translate(GetType(NTAccount)).Value
```

The entire function is below:

```
 Shared Function GetGroupNames() As List(Of String)
        'Returns a list of all groups the current user is a member of.  Called from CheckAccess.
        Dim groups As New List(Of String)
        For Each id_ref As IdentityReference In WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups
            Dim group As String = id_ref.Translate(GetType(NTAccount)).Value
            If group.Contains("\") Then
                'Remove unneeded domain info.
                group = group.Split("\")(1).ToLower
            End If
            groups.Add(group)
        Next
        Return groups
    End Function
```

Comment: Try the following: `Dim group As String = id_ref?.Translate(GetType(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).Value` and also `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(group) AndAlso group.Contains("\") Then`. See the following article for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem and my function now works perfectly!  Plus, that .? null conditional operator is something I didn't previously know that will likely be useful in the future.  Excellent!

Comment: If you want me to mark this as the answer, just post it as the answer and I will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that `id_ref` isn't null before calling `Translate`.

**Option 1**:

`Dim group As String = id_ref?.Translate(GetType(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).Value`

**GetGroupNames**

```
Shared Function GetGroupNames() As List(Of String)
    'Returns a list of all groups the current user is a member of.  Called from CheckAccess.
    Dim groups As New List(Of String)

    For Each id_ref As System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference In System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups
        Dim group As String = id_ref?.Translate(GetType(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).Value

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(group) Then
            If group.Contains("\") Then
                'Remove unneeded domain info.
                group = group.Split("\")(1).ToLower
            End If

            groups.Add(group)
        End If
    Next

    Return groups
End Function
```

**Note**: See [?. and ?() null-conditional operators (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) for more info.

**Option 2**:

**GetGroupNames**

```
Shared Function GetGroupNames() As List(Of String)
    'Returns a list of all groups the current user is a member of.  Called from CheckAccess.
    Dim groups As New List(Of String)

    For Each id_ref As System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference In System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups

        If id_ref IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim group As String = id_ref.Translate(GetType(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).Value

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(group) Then
                If group.Contains("\") Then
                    'Remove unneeded domain info.
                    group = group.Split("\")(1).ToLower
                End If

                groups.Add(group)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return groups
End Function
```